# When i run heroku run rake db:migrate getting SystemStackError: stack level too deep?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When i run the following command am getting the error as mentioned below.

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate
```

[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQT5T.png)

Please help me in getting out of the issue.

Comment: Getting error as stack level too deep.

Comment: Kindly post the migration file's content.

Comment: migration means schema file or complete migration

Comment: Not schema, the migration file.

Answer (score 0):

We need more code to accurate answer. But something I can say is that the `SystemStackError` can came when there's a [stack overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow). This is because you have a wrong ActiveRecord request, making a loop somewhere in you migration.

Please link your migration content for more details.

Hope it helps a bit!